# The role of input_tensors in tf.keras.models.clone_model

Tags: keras, model, cloning

I am trying to copy a existing keras model. The following is a sample code that I created and it seems that it's working as expected.

```
model = CreateSimpleModel()
model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
                 optimizer="adam",
                 metrics=["accuracy"])

model.summary()


model_cloned = tf.keras.models.clone_model(model)
model_cloned.set_weights(model.get_weights())

print(model(np.array([[1, 2]])))
print(model_cloned(np.array([[1, 2]])))
```

However, if we take a look at the official documentation about `tf.keras.models.clone_model` in the following page,there is a parameter named `input_tensors`.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/models/clone_model

I am not very sure about the role of this parameter. From the above sample code, I don't clearly understand why it is needed in some cases. Could anyone explain with some examples?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: Please don't do what I've done below. Having used GradCAM to look at what weights are being used in the first convolutional layer, it seems that the input_tensors argument doesn't have any impact and all clones of the base_model have the same weights despite the change in inputs.**

In my case, I am using tf.keras.models.clone_model to clone the base pre-trained neural network so that all of my multiple inputs have their own path:

```
# inputs:
x1 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None, None, 3), name="x1")
x2 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None, None, 3), name="x2")
x3 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None, None, 3), name="x3")

# load base model:
base_model = tf.keras.applications.DenseNet169(input_tensor=x1, input_shape=(224, 224, 3), include_top=False, pooling='avg')

# create copies:
base_model2 = tf.keras.models.clone_model(base_model, input_tensors=x2)
base_model3 = tf.keras.models.clone_model(base_model, input_tensors=x3)

# you have to rename the layers in each model so there aren't any conflicts:
cnt = 0
for mod in [base_model1, base_model2, base_model3, base_model4, base_model5, base_model6]:
    cnt += 1
    for layer in mod.layers:
        old_name = layer.name
        layer._name = f"base_model{cnt}_{old_name}"

# this bit isn't necessary unless you want to access weights easily later on:
base1_out = base_model.output
base2_out = base_model2.output
base3_out = base_model3.output

# concatenate the outputs:
concatenated = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([base1_out, base2_out, base3_out], axis=-1)

# add dense layers if you want:
concat_dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2048)(concatenated)
out = tf.keras.layers.Dense(class_count, activation='softmax')(concat_dense)

tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=[x1, x2, x3], outputs=[out])
```

Note that my inputs (in the form of a dictionary) come from symbolic tensors created with TensorFlow's tf.data.Dataset.